# create XML File using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to create a XML File (1.0) via PHP but I have problems with using `DOMDocument`.

My code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/xml');
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$root = $xml->createElement('root');
$root->setAttribute('id', '1234');
$root->setAttribute('date', '26.02.2018');
//info
$xml->appendChild($root);
$info = $xml->createElement('information');
$root->appendChild($info);
//updates
$updates = $xml->createElement('updates');
$info->appendChild($updates);
//updated
$updated= $xml->createElement('updated');
$updates->appendChild($updated);
//client
$client = $xml->createElement('client', 'exampleClient');
$updates->appendChild($updated);
//clientID
$clientID = $xml->createElement('clientID', '123456');
echo $xml->saveXML();
?>
```

Output:

```
<root id="1234" date="26.02.2018">
    <information>
        <updates>
            <updated/>
        </updates>
    </information>
</root>
```

As you can see, it doesn't display the `createElement()` Data like 'client' and 'exampleClient'.

My desired output:

```
<root id="1234" date="26.02.2018">
<information>
    <updates>
        <updated>
            <client>exampleClient</client>
            <clientID>123456</clientID>
        </updated>
    </updates>
</information>
</root>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve the problem?

Comment: For your further development: Please avoid code like `new DOMDocument` and use namespaces instead of classnames like `new Vendor/DOMDocument`

Comment: You created the `client` and `clientID` elements but you didn't attach them to the XML document. Of course they don't show up in the output of  `$xml->saveXML()`.

Comment: You have many unclosed questions, IMHO. Please have a look to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 . For all other anwsers and futur readers. Thank you!

Comment: @unherz thanks for the hint! @ axiac thank you, now it works

Answer (score 2):

You're missing to append `$client` and `$clientID` into `$updated`:

```
$updated->appendChild($client);
$updated->appendChild($clientID);
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: thank you, now it works correct! i will vote your answer up if i will have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You Can also use code to get your answer

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');

    $xml->addAttribute( "id", "123" );
    $xml->addAttribute("date", "26.02.2018" );
    $information = $xml->addChild('information');
    $updates = $information->addChild('updates');
    $updated = $updates->addChild('updated');
    $client = $updated->addChild('client','exampleClient');
    $clientID = $updated->addChild('clientID','123456');
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```